Installing packer plugin gives permission denied
I'm trying to create a packer build as follows, and am getting permission denied.
PACKER_LOG=1 packer init .
+ PACKER_LOG=1
+ packer init .
2024/05/06 11:35:03 [INFO] Packer version: 1.10.3 [go1.20.12 linux amd64]
2024/05/06 11:35:03 [TRACE] discovering plugins in /usr/bin
2024/05/06 11:35:03 [TRACE] discovering plugins in .
2024/05/06 11:35:03 [TRACE] discovering plugins in /home/userid/.config/packer/plugins
2024/05/06 11:35:03 [INFO] PACKER_CONFIG env var not set; checking the default config file path
2024/05/06 11:35:03 [INFO] PACKER_CONFIG env var set; attempting to open config file: /home/userid/.packerconfig
2024/05/06 11:35:03 [WARN] Config file doesn't exist: /home/userid/.packerconfig
2024/05/06 11:35:03 [INFO] Setting cache directory: /home/userid/.cache/packer
2024/05/06 11:35:03 [TRACE] init: plugingetter.ListInstallationsOptions{FromFolders:[]string{"/usr/bin", ".", "/home/userid/.config/packer/plugins"}, BinaryInstallationOptions:plugingetter.BinaryInstallationOptions{APIVersionMajor:"5", APIVersionMinor:"0", OS:"linux", ARCH:"amd64", Ext:"", Checksummers:[]plugingetter.Checksummer{plugingetter.Checksummer{Type:"sha256", Hash:(*sha256.digest)(0xc00035d400)}}}}
2024/05/06 11:35:03 [TRACE] listing potential installations for "github.com/hashicorp/vsphere" that match "~> 1". plugingetter.ListInstallationsOptions{FromFolders:[]string{"/usr/bin", ".", "/home/userid/.config/packer/plugins"}, BinaryInstallationOptions:plugingetter.BinaryInstallationOptions{APIVersionMajor:"5", APIVersionMinor:"0", OS:"linux", ARCH:"amd64", Ext:"", Checksummers:[]plugingetter.Checksummer{plugingetter.Checksummer{Type:"sha256", Hash:(*sha256.digest)(0xc00035d400)}}}}
2024/05/06 11:35:03 [TRACE] getting available versions for the github.com/hashicorp/vsphere plugin
2024/05/06 11:35:03 [WARNING] github-getter: no GitHub token set, if you intend to install plugins often, please set the PACKER_GITHUB_API_TOKEN env var
2024/05/06 11:35:03 [DEBUG] github-getter: getting "https://api.github.com/repos/hashicorp/packer-plugin-vsphere/git/matching-refs/tags"
2024/05/06 11:35:04 [DEBUG] will try to install: [1.2.7 1.2.6 1.2.5 1.2.4 1.2.3 1.2.2 1.2.1 1.2.0 1.1.2 1.1.1 1.1.0 1.0.8 1.0.7 1.0.6 1.0.5 1.0.4 1.0.3 1.0.2 1.0.1 1.0.0]
2024/05/06 11:35:04 [TRACE] fetching checksums file for the "1.2.7" version of the github.com/hashicorp/vsphere plugin in "/home/userid/.config/packer/plugins/github.com/hashicorp/vsphere"...
2024/05/06 11:35:04 [DEBUG] github-getter: getting "https://github.com/hashicorp/packer-plugin-vsphere/releases/download/v1.2.7/packer-plugin-vsphere_v1.2.7_SHA256SUMS"
2024/05/06 11:35:04 [TRACE] ignoring invalid remote binary packer-plugin-vsphere_v1.2.7_x5.0_darwin_amd64.zip: wrong system, expected linux_amd64
2024/05/06 11:35:04 [TRACE] ignoring invalid remote binary packer-plugin-vsphere_v1.2.7_x5.0_darwin_arm64.zip: wrong system, expected linux_amd64
2024/05/06 11:35:04 [TRACE] ignoring invalid remote binary packer-plugin-vsphere_v1.2.7_x5.0_freebsd_386.zip: wrong system, expected linux_amd64
2024/05/06 11:35:04 [TRACE] ignoring invalid remote binary packer-plugin-vsphere_v1.2.7_x5.0_freebsd_amd64.zip: wrong system, expected linux_amd64
2024/05/06 11:35:04 [TRACE] ignoring invalid remote binary packer-plugin-vsphere_v1.2.7_x5.0_freebsd_arm.zip: wrong system, expected linux_amd64
2024/05/06 11:35:04 [TRACE] ignoring invalid remote binary packer-plugin-vsphere_v1.2.7_x5.0_linux_386.zip: wrong system, expected linux_amd64
2024/05/06 11:35:04 [TRACE] About to get: packer-plugin-vsphere_v1.2.7_x5.0_linux_amd64.zip
2024/05/06 11:35:04 [DEBUG] github-getter: getting "https://github.com/hashicorp/packer-plugin-vsphere/releases/download/v1.2.7/packer-plugin-vsphere_v1.2.7_x5.0_linux_amd64.zip"
Installed plugin github.com/hashicorp/vsphere v1.2.7 in "/home/userid/.config/packer/plugins/github.com/hashicorp/vsphere/packer-plugin-vsphere_v1.2.7_x5.0_linux_amd64"
2024/05/06 11:35:05 [INFO] (telemetry) Finalizing.
2024/05/06 11:35:06 waiting for all plugin processes to complete...
++ date +%Y%m%dt%H%M%S
+ packer build -var vm_name=name-here -var-file=pkrvars/pkrvars.hcl .
 Error loading configuration:

fork/exec /home/userid/.config/packer/plugins/github.com/hashicorp/vsphere/packer-plugin-vsphere_v1.2.7_x5.0_linux_amd64: permission denied

Yet, the directory permissions look fine to me:
[userid@host  vsphere]$ ls -la  /home/userid/.config/packer/plugins
total 0
drwxr-xr-x. 3 userid userid 24 May  6 11:35 .
drwxr-xr-x. 3 userid userid 73 May  6 11:35 ..
drwxr-xr-x. 3 userid userid 23 May  6 11:35 github.com

[userid@host  vsphere]$ ls -la  /home/userid/.config/packer/plugins/github.com/hashicorp/vsphere/
total 61096
drwxr-xr-x. 2 userid userid      122 May  6 11:35 .
drwxr-xr-x. 3 userid userid       21 May  6 11:35 ..
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 userid userid 62558208 May  6 11:35 packer-plugin-vsphere_v1.2.7_x5.0_linux_amd64
-rw-r--r--. 1 userid userid       64 May  6 11:35 packer-plugin-vsphere_v1.2.7_x5.0_linux_amd64_SHA256SUM


[userid@host  vsphere]$ file packer-plugin-vsphere_v1.2.7_x5.0_linux_amd64
packer-plugin-vsphere_v1.2.7_x5.0_linux_amd64: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, stripped

I get the same error if I replace the build statement with:
PACKER_LOG=1 packer plugins install github.com/hashicorp/vsphere

That said, I have a feeling it has something to do with the following, i.e. that I can't run ./executable.
[userid@host  vsphere]$ vi test.sh
[userid@host  vsphere]$ chmod 0755 test.sh
[userid@host  vsphere]$ ./test.sh
-bash: ./test.sh: Permission denied

[userid@host  vsphere]$ bash test.sh
This is a test

[userid@host vsphere]$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash

echo "This is a test"

In the same way, executing the plugin executable doesn't work, either:
[userid@host vsphere]$ . ./packer-plugin-vsphere_v1.2.7_x5.0_linux_amd64
-bash: .: ./packer-plugin-vsphere_v1.2.7_x5.0_linux_amd64: cannot execute binary file
[user@host vsphere]$ ./packer-plugin-vsphere_v1.2.7_x5.0_linux_amd64
-bash: ./packer-plugin-vsphere_v1.2.7_x5.0_linux_amd64: Permission denied
[user@host vsphere]$ export PATH=${PATH}:.
[user@host vsphere]$ packer-plugin-vsphere_v1.2.7_x5.0_linux_amd64
-bash: ./packer-plugin-vsphere_v1.2.7_x5.0_linux_amd64: Permission denied

I don't think it's SELinux related, as the output below looks fine to me.
[user@host vsphere]$ ls -latZ .
total 61104
drwxr-xr-x. 2 userid userid unconfined_u:object_r:config_home_t:s0     4096 May  6 15:17 .
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 userid userid unconfined_u:object_r:config_home_t:s0       35 May  6 15:17 test.sh
-rw-r--r--. 1 userid userid unconfined_u:object_r:config_home_t:s0        0 May  6 14:56 plugins.hwm
-rw-r--r--. 1 userid userid unconfined_u:object_r:config_home_t:s0        0 May  6 14:56 plugins.pwd
-rw-r--r--. 1 userid userid unconfined_u:object_r:config_home_t:s0        0 May  6 14:56 plugins.pwi
-rw-r--r--. 1 userid userid unconfined_u:object_r:config_home_t:s0       64 May  6 11:35 packer-plugin-vsphere_v1.2.7_x5.0_linux_amd64_SHA256SUM
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 userid userid unconfined_u:object_r:config_home_t:s0 62558208 May  6 11:35 packer-plugin-vsphere_v1.2.7_x5.0_linux_amd64
drwxr-xr-x. 3 userid userid unconfined_u:object_r:config_home_t:s0       21 May  6 11:35 ..

Any thoughts as to how I can get the packer plugin working?

Since the root cause is probably related to your Linux environment, then you may have better results from asking on SuperUser.
